# angular - openLayers : zoom on geometry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3, directive

I'm using Openlayers directives for my project.
I was able to draw a geometry on the map, now i'd like to zoom on it.

I saw this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html?q=geometry) and it's exactly what i want to do (the best fit part).
But i don't know how to do it with Angular Directive.

here's my layer in my component controller :

```
            _this.perimeterLayer = {
            source: {
                type: 'GeoJSON',
                geojson: {
                    object: {
                        type: 'Feature',
                        geometry: {
                            type: 'Polygon',
                            coordinates: transformedCoords
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'blue',
                    width: 3
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
                })
            })
        };
```

and how i use it in my view :

```
  <ol-layer ol-layer-properties="$ctrl.perimeterLayer"></ol-layer>
```

can you help me?

thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution, i drop it here, maybe it can help!

the aim is to get your layers from the map, then parse the datas until you can get the geometry.

here's the function I did (a bit raw, but it's working)

```
        function perimeterFocus() {
        var geometry;
        olData.getMap().then(function (map) {
            map.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr) {
                if (lyr.get('name') == 'perimterLayer') {
                    var features = lyr.getSource().getFeatures();
                    geometry = features[0].getGeometry();
                    map.getView().fit(geometry, map.getSize());
                }
            });
        });
    }
```